# エラーになる意味がよくわからない

Tags: java

Javaのプログラムで質問です。

以下に、長方形の面積と円の面積を半径を表示するプログラム「Shape.java」「Circle.java」「Rectangle.java」「ShapeTester.java」の4つを示します。

Shape.java

```
public interface Shape {
    /** 図形を表示する　*/
    void print();

    /** 面積を返す */
    double getArea();
}
```

Circle.java

```
public class Circle implements Shape {
    /** 円周率 */
    public static final double PI = 3.14;
    
    private double r;

    public Circle(double r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

    /** 図形を表示する　*/
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("半径 " + r + "の円です．");
    }

    /** 面積を返す */
    public double getArea() {
        return PI * r * r;
    }

    /** 円周を返す */
    public double getLength() {
        return 2 * PI * r;
    }
}
```

Rectangle.java

```
public class Rectangle implements Shape {
    private double a, b;

    public Rectangle(double a, double b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    /** 図形を表示する　*/
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(a + " x " + b + "の長方形です．");
    }

    /** 面積を返す */
    public double getArea() {
        return a * b;
    }
}
```

ShapeTester.java

```
public class ShapeTester {
    public static void info(Shape s) {
        s.print();
        System.out.println("面積 = " + s.getArea());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Shape s1 = new Rectangle(2.5, 4.0);
        info(s1);

        Circle c = new Circle(1.0);
        info(c);
        System.out.println("cの円周 = " + c.getLength());

        Shape s2 = c;
        info(s2);
        System.out.println("s2の円周 = " + s2.getLength());
    }
}
```

しかし、このままコンパイルするとエラーメッセージが以下のように出てきてしまうので

```
~/java$ javac Shape.java
~/java$ javac Rectangle.java
~/java$ javac Circle.java
~/java$ javac ShapeTester.java
ShapeTester.java:17: エラー: シンボルを見つけられません
        System.out.println("s2の円周 = " + s2.getLength());
                                          ^
  シンボル:   メソッド getLength()
  場所: タイプShapeの変数 s2
エラー1個
```

一応、`System.out.println("s2の円周 = " + s2.getLength());` を削除したら、きちんとコンパイルが通りました。
しかし、なぜ `System.out.println("s2の円周 = " + s2.getLength());` が必要ないのかが、エラーメッセージを読んでもよくわからなかったので、教えていただきたい次第です。

Comment: `Shape.java` で宣言されている `Shape` interface に `double getLength();` がないから、です。

Comment: コメント欄は回答を書く場所ではありません。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

そのエラーメッセージは、getLengthがない、といっています
Shapeにはそういうメソッドがないですよね